# Sur les Groupes Hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov, English Version

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-groups

I would like to enquire whether or not the Book **Sur les Groupes Hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov** for the authors **Étienne Ghys** and **da la Harpe** (that is written in French) has been translated into English.

or, any English book with the same contents.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I don't think so.  See also [this previous question](/q/3449019/).

Comment: @user10354138 Do you know any English book dicuss the the same ideas of Sur les Groupes Hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov? (the same contents).

Comment: @Narasimham what do you mean?

Comment: Try "Notes on word-hyperbolic groups", by J.M.Alonso, T.Brady, D.Cooper, V.Ferlini, M.Lustig, M.Mihalik, M.Shapiro, H.Short; in Group Theory from a Geometric Viewpoint, World Scientific, 1991, pp. 3-63

Comment: He can be directly contacted at etienne.ghys@ ens-lyon.fr  or acadamie-sciences.fr of Lyon univ ... got  from his website.

Comment: @LeeMosher to be honest, I am actually looking for a highly recommended reference on topics such as Growth and Quasi-Isometry.

Comment: Then you should write your question to more clearly express what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a student led unofficial translation project on Sur les groupes hyperboliques d’après Mikhael Gromov

https://cheentan.com/translation-project-on-about-hyperbolic-groups-after-mikhail-gromov-by-etienne-ghys-and-pierre-de-la-harpe/